# Python Qt5 binding in Anaconda-5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, anaconda, pyqt5

All

just installed Anaconda-5, Python 3.6, Windows 10 pro, 64bit.

Matplotlib scripts (used to work with Anaconda-4, Python 3.5) refuse to work with message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\fit_gamma.py", line 5, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 16, in <module>
from .backend_qt5 import QtCore
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 26, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\figureoptions.py", line 20, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as formlayout
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_editor\formlayout.py", line 56, in <module>
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", line 128, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Anyone has a clue why it happens?

UPDATE

Apparently, notebook matplotlib backend works fine, graphs were drawn as computed

My Matplotlib standalone backend is qt5

> (How) did you install this?

Downloaded Anaconda-5 64bit blob installed and installed it. Python is added to PATH.

Conda list qt produced

```
pyqt                      5.6.0            py36hb5ed885_5         
qt                        5.6.2           vc14h6f8c307_12  [vc14] 
qtawesome                 0.4.4            py36h5aa48f6_0         
qtconsole                 4.3.1            py36h99a29a9_0         
qtpy                      1.3.1            py36hb8717c5_0
```

Comment: What is your Matplotlib backend? It seems that Matplotlib wants to import Qt5. (How) did you install this? Can you show the output of the `conda list qt` command?

Comment: @titusjan thank you, please check update